# Instruction cache for pipelined simulator

Tags: caching, pipeline

I am trying to complete a simulator based for a simplified mips computer using java. I believe I have completed the pipeline logic needed for my assignment but I am having a hard time understanding what the instruction and data caches are supposed to do.

The instruction cache should be direct-mapped with 4 blocks and the block size is 4 words.

So I am really confused on what the cache is doing. Is it going to memory and pulling the instruction from memory? For example, in one block it will have just the add command.

Would it make sense to implement it as a 2 dimensional array?

Answer (score 0):

First you should know the basics of the cache. You can imagine cache as an intermediate memory which sits between the DRAM or main memory and your processor, however very much limited in size. Now, when you try to access a location in memory, you will search it first in the cache. If it is found (cache hit) the processor will take this data and resume the execution. Generally the cache hit is supposed to be very few clock cycles lets say 1 or 2. Suppose if the data is not found in the cache (cache miss), then the data is fetched from the main memory, filled in the cache and fed to the processor. The processor blocks till the data is fetched. This takes few hundreds of clock cycles normally depending on the DRAM you are using. The amount of data that is fetched from DRAM is equal to cacheline size. For that you should search for spatial locality of reference in caches.

I think this should get you a start.